# Is it possible for turn signals to be operated with push to make switches to earth on a bike using relays?if so is there any circuit diagrams to show?

Tags: transistors, led, wire, powermosfet, wire-terminals

Switches are earthed when pressed. I have tried various ways of attaching the wires, but can’t find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use screws to attach wires ... crimp-on connectors may also work ... it all depends where the wires are being connected

Comment: I’m wiring the trike from new, but can’t get the turn signal wiring to work, because the switches are push to make (momentary switches) one side of the switch is earthed.

Comment: 12 volt indicator turn signal circuit diagram using relays and two single push to make buttons one for left turn, one for right turn. Is it even possible using the same switch to cancel the turn signal? Please send link to view diagram.